# How to ignore JSON property basing on the other property value in .NET using System.Text.Json serializer?

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I am having an exemplary .NET class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to serialize Name property only if Age is > 18 using JsonSerializer.Serialize(...) method? Would it be possible to achieve such behaviour without implementing custom serializer, eg. using some attributes? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't want any custom serializers your can try this code. It returns Name property value  eguals null if Age < 19. When Name is null, serializer ignores this property.

```
public class Foo
{
    private string _name;

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("Name")]
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public string _Name
    {
        get { return Age > 18 ? _name : null; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either write [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to) for the type or use [.NET 7 approach with customizing contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts):

```cs
var foos = new[] { new Foo { Age = 1, Name = "Should not show" }, new Foo { Age = 19, Name = "Name" } };

var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foos, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { SkipUnderagedName }
    }
});

Console.WriteLine(result); // prints "// [{"Age":1},{"Name":"Name","Age":19}]"

static void SkipUnderagedName(JsonTypeInfo ti)
{
    if (ti.Type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(Foo)))
    {
        var prop = ti.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == nameof(Foo.Name));
        if (prop is not null)
        {
            prop.ShouldSerialize = (obj, _) =>
            {
                var foo = obj as Foo;
                return foo?.Age >= 18;
            };
        }
    }
}
```